# Accessing passed in parent object when destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am passing an object to a function. I want to destructure some of the child object, but also have a reference to the original parent object. I hope this illustrates what I mean :

```
let state = {
    objectA: {},
    objectB: {},
    objectC: {}
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ objectA, objectB}, state) => {

    let a = objectA;
    let b = objectB;
    let c = state.objectC;
};

mapStateToProps(state);
```

I want to be able to destructure some of the objects, but then also have a reference to the original state object.

Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: Just don't destructure in the parameter list if you want to access the whole argument.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a classic function and use `arguments`.

In [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), you have no access to `arguments`.

```js
let state = { objectA: {}, objectB: {}, objectC: {} }

const mapStateToProps = function ({ objectA, objectB }) {
    let a = objectA;
    let b = objectB;
    let c = arguments[0].objectC;
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
};

mapStateToProps(state);
```